# how to change the language of TexStudio?

Tags: texstudio

I have downloaded TexStudio with MikTex, after installation TexStudio is in German version. How can I turn it into english?

Comment: Try: Optionen -> TeXstudio konfigurieren -> Allgemein -> Sprache -> en

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Menu `Optionen`, select `TeXstudio konfigurieren`, and in the popup window, in line `Sprache` replace `de` with `en`, like this:

[image]